# is it possible using PTC Windchill CLI to retrieve all issues IDs given a document ID?

Tags: command-line-interface, ptc-windchill

I have a document ID and i would like to retrieve all the sub issues IDs contained in it. Is it feasible via CLI?

I tried to use:

```
im viewissue ID
```

but the closest i get to the IDs information is how many are there, under 'All Content Count' field.

I also tried to use some options such as '--showBranches', '--showRelationships', ... but they don't return what I'm searching for.

This is an example structure of the document:

[image]